# Azure Data factory pipeline and dependent triggers

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

I am trying to list all of my ADF pipelines and their dependent triggers.
As per this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggers/get there is a simple GET method which will list all the triggers with their associated pipelines.
This is working fine when I use a web activity with GET method in ADF pipeline.
I am trying to do the same using powershell. The pipeline name which is visible in ADF output is no longer visible when running via powershell.

Can someone please help me with the code below to identify what needs to be added to fetch the dependent pipeline name for a trigger when this GET method is executed. Any other approach will also be highly appreciated.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$azContext = Get-AzContext
$azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($azProfile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($azContext.Subscription.TenantId)
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $token.AccessToken
}

$restUri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/1111111-1111-1111-11111-1111111/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/DataFactoryName/triggers?api-version=2018-06-01'

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Header $authHeader -URI $restUri 
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Powershell Output - Using powershell 5.1 via Azure runbook

```
"value":  [
                  {
                      "id":  "/subscriptions/1234-1234-1234-1234/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/DataFactoryName/triggers/eventbasedtrigger",
                      "name":  "eventbasedtrigger",
                      "type":  "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers",
                      "properties":  "@{description=Tets Trigger; annotations=System.Object[]; runtimeState=Stopped; pipelines=System.Object[]; type=BlobEventsTrigger; typeProperties=}",
                      "etag":  "000000-0000-0d00-0000-0000000"
                  },
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Powershell command Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger will provide you the list of triggers for an ADF pipeline / data factory

1. To get information about all the triggers in ADF:

> Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "<RG_NAME>"
> -DataFactoryName "<ADF_NAME>"

2. Get information about a specific trigger

> Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "<RG_NAME>" -DataFactoryName "<ADF_NAME>" -TriggerName "<TRIGGER_NAME>"

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. This command just provides the trigger details but not the pipeline dependency. I am looking for something using which I can link the trigger with the pipeline it is associated with.